# rsync does not follow symlink

Tags: rsync, symlink

I want to copy one file from one Linux server to another one:

Firstly, I've checked the following:

```
ls -l /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 mar 28 19:50 /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem -> ../../archive/example.com/fullchain260.pem
```

and

```
ls -l /etc/letsencrypt/archive/example.com/fullchain260.pem 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3578 mar 28 19:50 /etc/letsencrypt/archive/example.com/fullchain260.pem
```

then:

`rsync  -e "ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub" -uvvvvvL --chmod=F644 /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem soporte.example.com:/etc/pki/tls/certs/soporte.example.com/tmp`

```
cmd=ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub machine=soporte.example.com user=<NULL> path=/etc/pki/tls/certs/soporte.example.com/tmp
cmd[0]=ssh cmd[1]=-i cmd[2]=~/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub cmd[3]=soporte.example.com cmd[4]=rsync cmd[5]=--server cmd[6]=-vvvvvue.LsfxC cmd[7]=. cmd[8]=/etc/pki/tls/certs/soporte.example.com/tmp 
opening connection using: ssh -i "~/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub" soporte.example.com rsync --server -vvvvvue.LsfxC . /etc/pki/tls/certs/soporte.example.com/tmp  (9 args)
msg checking charset: UTF-8
FILE_STRUCT_LEN=24, EXTRA_LEN=4
(Server) Protocol versions: remote=31, negotiated=31
(Client) Protocol versions: remote=31, negotiated=31
FILE_STRUCT_LEN=24, EXTRA_LEN=4
[sender] change_dir(/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com)
[sender] make_file(fullchain.pem,*,0)
[sender] flist start=0, used=1, low=0, high=0
[sender] i=0 /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com fullchain.pem mode=0100644 len=3,578 flags=1000
send_file_list done
[sender] flist_eof=1
file list sent
send_files starting
server_recv(2) starting pid=1845
recv_file_name(fullchain.pem)
received 1 names
[Receiver] flist_eof=1
[Receiver] flist start=0, used=1, low=0, high=0
[Receiver] i=0 1 fullchain.pem mode=0100644 len=3,578 flags=1000
recv_file_list done
get_local_name count=1 /etc/pki/tls/certs/soporte.example.com/tmp
[Receiver] change_dir(/etc/pki/tls/certs/soporte.example.com)
generator starting pid=1845
delta-transmission enabled
recv_generator(tmp,0)
tmp is newer
generate_files phase=1
send_files phase=1
recv_files(1) starting
recv_files phase=1
generate_files phase=2
send_files phase=2
send files finished
total: matches=0  hash_hits=0  false_alarms=0 data=0
recv_files phase=2
recv_files finished
generate_files phase=3
generate_files finished
client_run waiting on 7070

sent 48 bytes  received 630 bytes  1,356.00 bytes/sec
total size is 3,578  speedup is 5.28
[sender] _exit_cleanup(code=0, file=main.c, line=1207): entered
[sender] _exit_cleanup(code=0, file=main.c, line=1207): about to call exit(0)
```

man pages of rysnc says: `-L, --copy-links            transform symlink into referent file/dir`

So the problem and the question are:

I want to copy the target of the symlink and the results is does nothing, but I don't see any errors. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: On `soporte.example.com` please provide result of `ls -ld /etc/pki/tls/certs/soporte.example.com/tmp`. If this shows it to be a directory please also repeat the command omitting the `-d` flag.